# http.get() didn't work but fetch() works on AppModule.ngDoBootstrap(), angular8

Tags: angular

when i try to load environment config before bootstrap app.component, first i use HttpClient http.get() to load environment.json from assets:

`service`

```
  init() {
    const url = 'assets/config/environment.json';
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }
```

`app.module`

```
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
// ...
  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.commonService.init().subscribe(env => {
      console.log(`env init`, env);
      appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
      // ...
    });
```

it didn't work.

---

then i use fetch() instead, it works.....but i don't konw why

`service`

```
  init() {
    return from(
      fetch('assets/config/environment.json', {
        method: 'GET'
      })
    );
  }
```

`app.module`

```
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
// ...
  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.commonService.init().subscribe(env => {
      console.log(`env init`, env);
      appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
      // ...
    });
```

---

```sh
Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 12.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.5
@angular/cdk                      8.2.1
@angular/cli                      8.3.5
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.6
@schematics/angular               8.3.5
@schematics/update                0.803.5
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch doesn't need any library to import for working with Angular that why it's working.

For Http, you have to user `HttpClient` is to be imported in service and `app.module` also import the `HttpClientModule`.

> Can you give more info? so we will help like
>
> - What imports are done in `service` and `app.module`?
>     - Is there any error in console?

You can also refer to [this](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

Comment: thanks. it's cause http interceptor. `  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let url = req.url;
    if (!url.startsWith('http://') && !url.startsWith('https://')) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }`